# warning at java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=75; regionStart=0; regionLength=100

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting warning on Logcat and I still can't find how to fix it. Maybe someone can show me the solution. And why can't logcat show all of my JSON? It just shows some of them. Is it normal or should I add something in my code?

```
11-19 12:40:46.296: I/.........(1644): [{"id":"119","judul":"Daftar Penerima Beasiswa Bidik Misi","kategori":"beasiswa","published":"2014-09-17 06:27:19","isi":"Silhkan klik link di bawah ini : Penerima Beasiswa Bidik Misi Terima kasih."},{"id":"118","judul":"Penerima Beasiswa Toyota dan Astra","kategori":"beasiswa","published":"2014-09-17 06:26:48","isi":"Kepada mahasiswa yang namanya tercantum dalam\u00a0link berikut ini Mohon segera datang ke kantor bikem untuk realisasi beasiswa Toyota dan Astra Terima kasih."},{"id":"117","judul":"BAKTI SOSIAL TANAM POHON DI KAMPUS III","kategori":"beasiswa","published":"2014-09-17 06:26:18","isi":"Seluruh penerima beasiswa UKSW diundang hadir (wajib) dalam acara tanam pohon pada hari Sabtu, 16 November 2012 jam 06.30 di kampus III. Mahasiswa langsung menuju ke kampus III desa blotongan dengan membawa air untuk menyiram, alat menanam, penyangga bibit dari bambu (tinggi 1 M dan lebar 4 cm), rafia, label nama dilapis plastik (10 cm x 12 cm) (lubang sudah disediakan) daftar ketua kelompok dan nomor HP dapat dilihat di papan pengumuman, info beasiswa, dan web."},{"id":"116","judul":"Pendidikan Agama Kelas H (Dosen : Bpk. Thobias Messakh)","kategori":"lainnya","published":"2014-09-17 06:25:24","isi":"Jadwal Matakuliah Pendidikan Agama Kelas H yang diampu oleh Bpk. Dr. Thobias Messakh ialah Hari Kamis, 16-18 Ruang di ABX102. Mohon untuk diperhatikan. Terima Kasih"},{"id":"115","judul":"Program MAGANG di PT. KIBAR KREASI INDONESIA","kategori":"lainnya","published":"2014-09-17 06:24:57","isi":"Kalau kamu anak muda yang mau bikin perubahan, tertarik bikin proyek yang berguna buat orang banyak, dan mau mencari pengalaman yang bisa memaksimalkan potensi kamu, yuk gabung... PT. KIBAR KREASI INDONESIA menajak Mahasiswa UKSW untuk bergabung dalam program Magang selama 2 Bulan...Syarat &amp; Ketentuan lebih lanjut bisa dilihat di link berikut :\u00a0http:\/\/goo.gl\/erZALk Terima Kasih. Salam, Google Student Ambassador"},{"id":"114","judul":"Panggilan Mahasiswa (DKV)","kategori":"lainnya","published":"2014-09-17 06:24:27","isi":"Panggilan kepada mahasiswa atas nama GLADYS HANNEKE LOUDY NIKIJULUW (692011055) mohon segera menghadap Bp. Michael di kantor pada hari Rabu, 17 September 2014 jam 12.00 WIB. Harap diperhatikan. \u00a0 Terima kasih, \u00a0 Salam, Michael"},{"id":"113","judul":"Panggilan Mahasiswa TI","kategori":"lowongan-pekerjaan","published":"2014-09-17 06:23:42","isi":"Mohon mahasiswa dengan NIM dibawah ini datang ke kantor kaprogdi S1 TI paling lambat hari Rabu, 4 Juni 2014. Berikut daftar NIM nya : - 67 2007 020 (Catur Heru Nugroho) - 67 2007 026 (Arya Berliandi) - 67 2007 156 (Ayu Wulan Sari) - 67 2007 183 (Andreas Vipri Nandha Gunadi S) - 67 2007 289 (Febriyanto Heri S) - 67 2009 003 (Georgius Teniwut) - 67 2010 612 - 67 2011 705 - 67 2011 712 - 67 2012 707 \u00a0 Demikian atas perhatiannya terima kasih \u00a0 Salam, Kaprogdi S1 TI"},{"id":"112","judul":"Undangan Pendidikan Publik (Jurnal Perempuan)","kategori":"lowongan-pekerjaan","published":"2014-09-17 06:23:06","isi":"Untuk info lebih lengkap silahkan klik\u00a0disini."},{"id":"111","judul":"Lowongan Kerja Formulatrix","kategori":"lowongan-pekerjaan","published":"2014-09-17 06:22:33","isi":"Berikut ini lowongan yang sedang dibuka saat ini di Formulatrix, silahkan klik link dibawah ini:  RnD Mechanical Design Engineer RnD Mechanical Design Engineer (Internship), special qualification: minimum 6 month - 1 year in the final year of study RnD Junior Electronic Engineer --\u00a0http:\/\/siva-id.jobstreet.com\/_ads\/id\/jobs\/2014\/7\/new\/p\/40\/1319232.htm?17145620 RnD Junior Electronic Engineer (Internship ), special qualification: Minimum 6 month - 1 year in the final year of study Firmware Engineer --\u00a0http:\/\/siva-id.jobstreet.com\/_ads\/id\/jobs\/2014\/7\/new\/p\/40\/1319217.htm?17145342 RnD Senior Software Engineer --\u00a0http:\/\/siva-id.jobstreet.com\/_ads\/id\/jobs\/2014\/7\/new\/p\/40\/1319207.htm?17144918 RnD Junior Software Engineer (Internship), special qualification: Minimum 6 month - 1 year in the final year of study HR
11-19 12:40:47.086: W/System.err(1644): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=75; regionStart=0; regionLength=100
11-19 12:40:47.086: W/System.err(1644):     at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:588)
11-19 12:40:47.106: W/System.err(1644):     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1475)
11-19 12:40:47.106: W/System.err(1644):     at com.example.cobalagi.AksesServerActivity$LoadAllPengumuman.doInBackground(AksesServerActivity.java:1)
11-19 12:40:47.106: W/System.err(1644):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-19 12:40:47.106: W/System.err(1644):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-19 12:40:47.106: W/System.err(1644):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-19 12:40:47.106: W/System.err(1644):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-19 12:40:47.106: W/System.err(1644):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-19 12:40:47.106: W/System.err(1644):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-19 12:40:47.106: W/System.err(1644):     at com.example.cobalagi.AksesServerActivity$LoadAllPengumuman.doInBackground(AksesServerActivity.java:111)
11-19 12:40:47.266: I/ActivityManager(1273): Displayed com.example.cobalagi/.AksesServerActivity: +1s932ms
11-19 12:40:47.266: I/Choreographer(1273): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-19 12:40:47.306: I/WindowManager(1273): Switching to real app window: Window{b32ad1f0 u0 com.example.cobalagi/com.example.cobalagi.AksesServerActivity}
11-19 12:40:53.626: D/dalvikvm(1380): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 533K, 16% free 3413K/4048K, paused 10ms, total 20ms
```

And this is my class:

```
public class AksesServerActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> daftar_pengumuman = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    private static String link_url = "http://10.0.2.2/Pengumuman/get_all_pengumuman.php";

    private static final String PNG_ID = "id";
    private static final String PNG_JUDUL = "judul";
    private static final String PNG_KATEGORI = "kategori";
    private static final String PNG_PUBLISHED = "published";
    private static final String PNG_ISI = "isi";

    JSONArray pengumuman = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        daftar_pengumuman = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadAllPengumuman().execute();
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String kode = ( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kode) ).getText().toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailAksesServer.class);
                in.putExtra(PNG_ID, kode);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }

    class LoadAllPengumuman extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AksesServerActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Pengumuman. Harap Tunggu . . .");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                Log.i(".........", "Hellooooo......");
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(link_url);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Log.i(".........", jsonString);
                //JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                //JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray(PNG_ID);

                //JSONObject json = jParser.ambilJson(link_url);

                //Log.d("Pengumuman:", json.toString());


                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

                for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject a = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    //String id = a.getString(PNG_ID);
                    String judul = a.getString(PNG_JUDUL);
                    String kategori = a.getString(PNG_KATEGORI);
                    String published = a.getString(PNG_PUBLISHED);
                    String isi = a.getString(PNG_ISI).substring(0, 100)+"...(baca selengkapnya)";                       
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    //map.put(PNG_ID, id);
                    map.put(PNG_JUDUL, judul);
                    map.put(PNG_KATEGORI, kategori);
                    map.put(PNG_PUBLISHED, published);
                    map.put(PNG_ISI, isi);

                    daftar_pengumuman.add(map);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //public void adapter_listview() {
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AksesServerActivity.this, daftar_pengumuman,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { PNG_JUDUL, PNG_KATEGORI, PNG_PUBLISHED, PNG_ISI, PNG_ID}, 
                        new int[] {R.id.judul, R.id.kategori, R.id.published, R.id.isi, R.id.kode });
                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void longLog(String str) {
        if (str.length() > 4000) {
            Log.d("", str.substring(0, 4000));
            longLog(str.substring(4000));
        } else
            Log.d("", str);
    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Just read the [doc about String.substring](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: its normal that it shows incomplete json. and regarding your error please post your full logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PNG_ISI` string is not 100 characters long, even though you ask for the system to return a substring that is 100 characters long. You can deal with this in two ways - first one being to skip the "read more" text if it is not 100 characters long, the other one being to just add a "read more" text after what you have regardless.

```
// if you only want a "read more" suffix for long strings
String isi = a.getString(PNG_ISI);
if (isi.length() >= 100) {
    isi = isi.substring(0, 100) + "...(baca selengkapnya)";
}

// if you want to always have a "read more" suffix
String isi = a.getString(PNG_ISI);
isi = isi.substring(0, Math.min(isi.length(), 100)) + "...(baca selengkapnya)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Before making a call that assumes something about the length of a String :

```
String isi = a.getString(PNG_ISI).substring(0, 100)+"...(baca selengkapnya)";
```

you must make sure that your String has at least 100 characters:

```
String isi = "";
String png = a.getString(PNG_ISI);
if (png.length() >= 100)
    isi = png.substring(0, 100)+"...(baca selengkapnya)";
else 
    // do something else
```